# UnitTest Django Views: Não consigo logar no sistema pelo unittest

Tags: python, testes, django

Preciso dar um `post` em uma view minha de "criação de pedidos", porém quando tento dar o `post`, eu sou redirecionado para minha tela de login, estou tentando logar no sistema para então dar o post nessa view, mas não obtive êxito. Alguém conseguiria me ajudar?

## tests.py

```py
class OrderRegisterView(TestCase):
    def test_order_register_view(self):
        c = Client()
        User.objects.create_user('teste', 'teste', 'teste')

        c.login(username='teste', password='teste', follow=True)
        response = c.post('/pedidos/cadastro/', {'username':'teste', 'password': 'teste','ship_date':'12/04/14', 'ship_time': 'morning', 'truck': 7, 'city': 4304606, 'value': 12, 'action': 'selected', 'cheapest': True}, follow=True)
        # self.assertRedirects(response, '/login/')
```

Não passo daí, aliás não me dá nenhum erro, apenas passa OK.

Comment: Você está tentando testar a View ou o Form? Caso esteja testando o form, o ideal é instanciá-lo dentro do teste com os valores que você quer usar.

Comment: O cadastro de pedidos que estou testando, passa pelo formulário e se ele for válido, a própria view, cria o objeto Order(), queria testar esse processo, por isso precisava apenas gerar o POST nessa minha view, para que ela crie o Order sozinha.

Comment: Sim, mas o que você quer testar exatamente? A validação dos dados do form ou a criação da Order pela view? Se for só a validação, você deve fazer o que orientei no comentário anterior; se for a criação do Order pela view: tente passar os dados através da kwarg `data=`, p.ex. `c.post('/pedidos/cadastro/', data={'username': 'teste'....}`.

Comment: Estou tentando testar a criação do Order pela view, estou fazendo exatamente isso, passando os parâmetros no post, mas quando dou o post no pedidos/cadastro, sou redirecionado para a tela de login, e não acontece nada, mesmo passando o username e pass no post, tentei de várias maneiras passar pela tela de login e nada aconteceu, por isso não consigo dar o post nessa tela de /pedidos/cadastro/

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um problema não relacionado ao que foi perguntado, já solucionado pelo autor da pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que alguma dessas 3 opções resolverá o problema:

### 1) Mude o test client:

Em vez de instanciar o client com `c = Client()`, use o client que já vem com o TestCase. Assim:

```
self.client.login(username='teste', password='teste', follow=True)
self.client.post('/pedidos/cadastro/', {'username':'teste', 'password': 'teste','ship_date':'12/04/14', 'ship_time': 'morning', 'truck': 7, 'city': 4304606, 'value': 12, 'action': 'selected', 'cheapest': True}, follow=True)
```

### 2) Tire o "follow=True" do login:

Nunca usei follow=True na chamada de login. Talvez seja isso.

```
self.client.login(username='teste', password='teste')
```

### 3) @login_required

Se ainda não estiver usando, faça a autenticação da view com o decorator `@login_required`.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade era uma verificação no dispatch da minha view.

Não era nada relacionado com sintaxe do código.

Mas de quaquer maneira, muito obrigado.

Abraços!